# I am trying to use an IF statement using a select IN clause. What is he correct syntax for the following T-SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2000; I am trying to determine the action if a value in a field of the INSERTED record matches one of several distinct values in a field in a table. Field y in tableB could be say 'one', 'two' or 'three'. The INSERTED record must be a single record, and therefore the field x must be a single value. Hence, given the code snippet below, what is the correct syntax? In particular where do the "()" go in the IF statement?

```
if select x from INSERTED in (select y from tableB) 
and <another condition>
begin

<some code>

end
```

Comment: When you have anything greater than a straightforward single comparison you need to wrap everything after the `IF`, but before the `BEGIN` in parentheses.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help if you could express what you are trying to accomplish. Having people guess at your intended meaning is a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE1    WHERE X IN (1,2))
Begin
 -- code
End
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the individual flag in variables and use that in IF condition.

```
Declare @chkExist int
Select @chkExist = Count(*) from tableA x in (select y from tableB) 

if ((@chkExist > 0) and (<another condition>))
begin

<some code>

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a "where exists" instead of "IN"

```
if exists ( select null from tableA taAlias where (select null from tableB tbAlias where tbAlias.y = taAlias.x ) )
and 1=1
begin

  Select 1 as 'YouNeedAtLeastOneLineOfCodeInThisBeginEnd'
end
```